# Does this decuplet make sense?

Tags: notation, tuplet

I recently encountered this decuplet as you can see in the picture attached.
To me this doesn't make sense. This makes 10 16th notes instead of 4. This reduces the notes' lentgh 2.5 times.

Should one not write this as 10 32th notes instead of 8? That would make more sense to me. Then the notes' length would only be reduced 1.25 times. Or better even: two quintuplets of 32th notes.

Moreover, this notation makes it impossible to determine how long it should be if not for the bass notes and the rest of the measure. Say for example you use this in an anacrusis, without the bass ...

[image]

Comment: For a recording, this is Chopin's Raindrop Prelude. I edited the post to spell 'base' as 'bass' for referring to the left hand notes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Theoretically, you're right, I think. Strictly, the example you show should be read as "play these 10 notes with the same duration that 8 normal 16th notes would have", i.e., the total duration of a half note, which does not fit the meter.

This may be a typesetting mistake, or a simplification for readability (a lot of beam lines in this case don't give a lot of useful information and clutter the score). I'm not saying it's right, but it's quite clear in this presentation what you're supposed to do.

BTW, looking at the pencil markings, it should be noted that the composer (if that's what the composer actually wrote) chose to write a dectuplet and not two qintuplets. That division may be useful when learning the piece, but care must be taken that the 10 notes sound as a continous fluid phrase, not as two separate phrases.

Answer (score 5):

This isn't going to be played with mathematical precision.  Along with the "smorzando", the choice of note value indicates a relaxed tempo related to the preceding 16th note, rather than something twice as fast.  As you say, there is plenty of information in the rest of the notation.

Comment: True. And probably in this style of music you will long have figured out how to play this before you perform it. But if it wasn't during a smorzando and someone wanted to play it on sight, it might confuse him enough for him to lose the correct tempo.

Comment: Yes, if it wasn't that, it could be something else.  But it IS that!

Answer (score 4):

What Chopin wrote:
[image: Chopin Raindrop Prelude bar 79]

It's `9` underneath, but there are ten notes and editions after (apart from Fontana's copying) show ten
(see [Online Chopin Variorum Edition at this bar, bar 79](https://www.chopinonline.ac.uk/ocve/browse/barview?workid=6355&pageimageid=72665&barid=79)).

My suggestion is that it is in fact 9 and the end three notes are a tuplet nested inside the 9.

Separately, `9` as a division is extremely unique where it can be expressed with two beams and also with three beams. Elaine Gould, 2011, *Behind Bars*, p.203, shows this in the table below:

[image]

Here is how I suggest it should be written:

[image]

And this is the pedantic way to write it out (which I would really doubt it existing in a Chopin holograph or any edition):

[image]

Comment: A dot of ink spilled and made an Ab5-like notehead. If Chopin wrote it using music notation software then ink drops cannot spill and I think it is like that. Here is [the bar with the 9-tuplet where the ink drop spilled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/esyRK.png) (the nested triplets should be a nonuplet).

Comment: @Vighnesh the notehead does resemble a spill, but there is ample evidence that it is not. Note the stem connecting to the beams above, and note the regular horizontal spacing of the ten stems (with slightly more space where accidentals are needed). Also note that there are several other places where mistakes have been very thoroughly scribbled out; such corrections are absent here. It is a bit weird that the stem extends beyond the ink blob; none of the other stems does. Perhaps an F♯5 was intended when he drew the stem and he changed his mind before writing the notehead.

Comment: There's '9' under the tuplet, so the stem should be a [headless](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/122711/what-is-the-meaning-of-headless-notes) [nachschlag](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Nachschlag). The ink drop spilled and the publisher thought Chopin made a mistake with the tuplet number and made it as a 10-tuplet. See this [screenshot of the German first edition from the IMSLP without a tuplet number](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5uYQC.png) and the [Karl Klindworth edition from IMSLP with the 10-tuplet number as well as a sub-group](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UmCmq.png)

Answer (score 2):

In the fourth bar of the same Chopin prelude you also find something equally suspicious from the point of view of modern notation practice. There it's seven notes written with a single beam even though their duration is just a quarter note. You'd understand it from context there as well.

Septuples can be confusing, and many people mistakenly would write, say, a septuple over a half note with double beams because each note's duration is so close to a 16th note.

But the rule would be to have the number of beams that would make the tuple, if read as 8th, 16th, 32th (etc) notes longer than the timespan it fits into, but shorter than the double timespan. (Maybe this can be stated much more clearly by someone?)

Comment: I didn't see that septuplet further in the prelude (it isn't my sheet music), so there it is actually the same "mistake"?

I agree that a tuple is always about more notes than the normal notation. So in the example you describe it should indeed be eighth notes since it is 7 instead of 4 and should not be 7 instead of 8.

Comment: "equally suspicious from the point of view of modern notation practice": the takeaway here is that it's not precisely measured, and anyway the meter should be extremely flexible, so even the quarter notes won't all have the same duration.  I recently heard Ivo Pogorelić play music of this period, which I normally find rather boring.  When he played, it seemed that there was no simultaneity.  Nothing ever happened at the same time as anything else, and it was genius.  @LuKas whatever it should be by modern rules, it seems fairly clear that Chopin just wanted a bunch of notes played quickly.

Answer (score -1):

On slow agogé it makes sense. But there is a big error in the score! the dectuplet must be formed by 10/32, NOT by 10/16 hehehe